# Could you use a hotspot to watch and override data going into a Chromebook?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I want to see how downloading works when you get an application from the Playstore on my Chromebook. I also want to be able to override files going into the Chromebook via the hotspot. I'm wondering if I could create a hotspot on my phone to do this, and if so how would I go across doing this. I want to know how to do this on my phone without modifying/installing anything on the Chromebook. I am fine with modifying/rooting the phone though.

Thanks for any help!

PS - Does anybody know of some better tags?

Comment: Services like PlayStore and PlayServices usually use HTTPS connection with certificate pinning. Thus network interception won't work without modifying the system and the services. Unfortunately Chromebooks are out of scope of this site as we are foxused on Android devices.

Comment: Is there any way to get past the certificate pinning without modifying the Chromebook?

Comment: No there is no way. On Android there is the possibility to use Frida or Magisk plus certain unpinning scripts/modules but in the end to make them run you need root and thus a modified system.

Comment: Do Fridaoror and Magisk root the phone or the Chromebook?

Comment: Magisk is a common framework for rooting an Android device but a Chromebook is totally different from Android even if it is capable of running Android apps. Frida is an app-manipulation and hacking framework that works for various platforms.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Regarding Robert's comment, just want to let you know that we have [this policy about Chromebook/Chrome OS](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2336/44325). Thus, if this is about operating the Android portion of Chromebook, then this question might be on-topic.

Comment: @Robert so could I use Frida on my phone to edit http requests going in and out of the chromebook?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I don't have any experience with Chromebook.

Comment: @Robert Okay, thanks for the help!